# Looks like a query string, but won't act as a query string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, query-string, request.querystring

I am working with VB in asp.net,

The basic problem is, I want to pair up the elements in a string, exactly like `request.QueryString()` will do to the elements in the query string of the web page.

However instead of the function looking at the current webpage query string I want it to look at a string (that is in the exact form of a query string) stored as a variable.

So if I define a string such as:

```
Dim LooksLikeAQueryString As String = "?category1=answer1&category2=answer2"
```

I want a function that if I input `LooksLikeAQueryString` and "category1" it outputs "answer1" etc.

Is there anything that can already do this or do I have to build my own function? If I have to build my own, any tips?

I should add that in this case I won't be able to append the string to the url and then run request.QueryString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) will do it for you - something along these lines:

```
Private Function QueryStringValue(queryString As String, key As String) As String
    Dim qscoll As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString)
    For Each s As String In qscoll.AllKeys
        If s = key Then Return qscoll(s)
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Usage:

```
    Dim LooksLikeAQueryString As String = "?category1=answer1&category2=answer2"
    Response.Write(QueryStringValue(LooksLikeAQueryString, "category2"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HttpUtility.ParseQueryString method - [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the dependancy of `System.Web`, of the top of my head

```
public string GetValue(string fakeQueryString,string key)
{
    return fakeQueryString.Replace("?",String.Empty).Split('&')
        .FirstOrDefault(item=>item.Split('=')[0] == key);
}
```